# What platforms need to include Microsoft.Bcl.* NuGet packages?

Tags: .net, nuget, portable-class-library, base-class-library

I maintain a library that targets multiple Windows and Xamarin platforms, and for backward compatibility its .nuspec definition lists the following Microsoft NuGet packages in the dependency list:

- Microsoft.Bcl
- Microsoft.Bcl.Build
- Microsoft.Bcl.Async

Since most of .NET developers have switched to .NET 4.5 or later, I'd like to revise the .nuspec and only list Bcl dependency for the platforms that need it. This is of course "net40", but what about "sl5"? Can I remove Bcl packages for other platforms (I don't target platforms prior net40)? What about latest Xamarin iOS and Android?

UPDATE. I noticed that Microsoft.Net.Http (that my library uses) includes both Microsoft.Bcl and Microsoft.Bcl.Build as dependencies. This actually means that I can only remove Microsoft.Bcl.Async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Silverlight (sl5) and .NET 4 (net40) target requires such packages. All .NET 4.5 above and Xamarin ones can live without them.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed to confirm.

Comment: Hm, but that only applies to Microsoft.Bcl.Async? I see that Microsoft.Net.Http lists both Microsoft.Bcl and Microsoft.Bcl.Build as dependencies.